# Slow to receive 1MB response in browser

Tags: servicestack

I've a test web service using SS 3.9.71, and I've a response (which is a list of 1400 objects).

The response is 827KB.

[image]

This is running on localhost on Windows 7.

This seems far too slow.

Logging out to the console takes no time, so its not a JSON Serialisation issue.

I'm wondering if I've something missing in my config that is contributing to the slowness that I'm seeing.  I'm using AppHostHttpListenerLongRunningBase.

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601;
ValidatorOptions.CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;
```

Any advice welcome.

Comment: Some code that works fast and code that works slow would be helpful.

Comment: Are you building and running the Release build of the application, or are you using a Debug build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out F5-ing from Visual Studio causes this.  Doesn't matter about Debug/Release builds, but attached debugger has significant impact, even when nothing is hitting.